# Kotlin use of JDK modules

Tags: java, kotlin, smartcardio

I'm currently writing Kotlin code that uses a Java library (developed by me) that uses `javax.smartcardio` lib, but on Kotlin compilation the following error is shown:

`Cannot access class 'javax.smartcardio.CommandAPDU'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies`

What can I do to solve this?

Thank you.

EDIT: I'm, using maven and my dependencies and plugins are as follows:

```
<properties>
    <kotlin.version>1.3.11</kotlin.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.javalin</groupId>
        <artifactId>javalin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Kotlin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
        <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>my.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>apdu-processor</artifactId>
        <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>testCompile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The library that is using `javax.smartcardio` is `apdu-processor`.

Comment: You might need to provide a bit more information like how you've set up your dependencies (e.g. have you used Gradle or Maven, what does the build script looks like, etc.)

Comment: Take a look now. If any other information is missing or/and needed please do tell.

Comment: Which of those dependencies should bring in the class that's causing the problem, i.e. `'javax.smartcardio.CommandAPDU`?

Comment: `apdu-processor`, it's my library.

Comment: What he's asking is in which library is `javax.smartcardio.CommandAPDU` class located, not which is library is using it.

Comment: @tynn Pasting error, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Since `javax.smartcardio` is not a direct dependency of your project, it needs to be declared transitively from `apdu-processor`. There you have to make sure that this dependency is declared as a *COMPILE* dependency, not *PROVIDED*, nor *RUNTIME*.

You could always fix it by declaring hte dependency explicitly in your project.

Comment: `apdu-processor` doesn't include the dependency in its `pom.xml`. Instead it uses the `--add-modules javax.smartcardio` Java flag to add it. Therefore this solution does not work.